# Whether a predictor with lot of zeroes should be included in logistic model

Tags: logistic

I have a set of predictors with zeroes in over 70% of the observations. These zeroes are actual zeroes and not because of missing information.Should I even try such predictors in my logistic model? If yes, what checks should I do before trying them in the model??

Comment: Just because it's skewed doesn't mean it's not a good predictor. You response might be correlated with it!! Try it and look at the model summaries. A predictor is only useless if it somehow can't be related to the outcome variable.

Answer (score 3):

yes,just check if it has any relation with dependent variable. As you said it has 0 in  more than 70% of observation, this may cause scarcity esp if other predictors also have 0s.

if this is the case, you might use L-1 regularization with logistic model, But having even 90% 0s is not the reason to exclude a variable in model. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Arpit Sisodia is correct. One example of using logistic regression with very sparse features (i.e., most feature values are 0) is text classification using n-grams as features and logistic regression as the classier. Well over 99.9% of feature values are 0, yet it works well and actually is difficult to significantly outperform (e.g. see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.05251v1.pdf table 2).